# Ошибка в приложении для парсинга

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Пытаюсь с помощью с jsoup парсить Яндекс и вывести на экран `title` яндекса.
В приложение не входит,вылетает окно "В приложении произошла ошибка" - Android 2.3.3
Вот собственно код:

```
public class IndexActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yandex.ru").get();
        String name = doc.title();
        System.out.println("Название страницы: " + name);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     

}

}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: нельзя работать с сетью в главном потоке.   
На будущее, если приложение вылетает, всегда смотрите на стактрейс ошибки. Он будет в LogCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно из-за того что Android начиная с версии 3й не может обращаться к сети из основного потока.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yandex.ru").get();
                String name = doc.title();
                System.out.println("Название страницы: " + name);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

И не забудьте про разрешение в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: не помогло. все равно вылетает из приложения сразу же при запуске

Comment: с вашим вариантом ошибок в LogCat , которые выделены красным, стало меньше. вот какие остались: 08-30 21:04:56.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
 | 08-30 21:04:56.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
| 08-30 21:04:56.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at by.vek.shop.IndexActivity$1.run(IndexActivity.java:25)
| 08-30 21:04:56.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Comment: Думаю что то не так в подключении либы Jsoup, поскольку класс не найден